# JRuby 1.7.0 will not install bundler given plenty of memory

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

I installed jruby with

```
rvm install jruby-1.7.0
```

and it ran out of memory when it tried to create the gemsets so I started by trying to install bundler with the new version and this is what I get

```
~>gem install bundler
Error: Your application used more stack memory than the safety cap of 2048K.
Specify -J-Xss####k to increase it (#### = cap size in KB).
Specify -w for full StackOverflowError stack trace
```

So I moved up the memory and I still got nothing with a huge chunk of memory

```
~>JRUBY_OPTS=-J-Xss1024m gem install bundler
Error: Your application used more stack memory than the safety cap of 1024M.
Specify -J-Xss####k to increase it (#### = cap size in KB).
Specify -w for full StackOverflowError stack trace
```

How the hell can that not be enough I run applications on less than that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
rvm get 1.15.11
rvm reinstall jruby-head
```

This appears to be an rvm issue:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6948 AND https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/331#issuecomment-9120273

Comment: That fixed the problem for me you can also do it for a specific version of the code jruby-1.7.3, etc.