# Jruby grabs all available memory and fails (used over RVM) - how to fix it?

Tags: ruby, rvm, jruby

when using jruby, even simple commands like `gem -v` fail. Initially, I got this error:

```
Error: Your application used more stack memory than the safety cap of 2048K.
Specify -J-Xss####k to increase it (#### = cap size in KB).
Specify -w for full StackOverflowError stack trace
```

After having read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038820/jruby-1-7-0-will-not-install-bundler-given-plenty-of-memory),and the linked issues I have updated my rvm, reloaded it, reinstalled jruby and exported `JRUBY_OPTS=-J-Xss32768k` (8192k still failed with the stack error) Cuurently, `rvm -v` returns `rvm 1.18.21 (latest)`, `rvm current` returns `jruby-1.7.3`. `gem -v` and other similar calls do not return anything. They start a java process which grabs all the available RAM (up to 7+ GB), run for 2-3 minutes and then finish silently without any effect.

Is there anything else I can do to fix this?

When I switch to another ruby, like `ruby-head`, all works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen because of older RVM which had extra code to support even older JRuby, update RVM and reinstall JRuby:

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall jruby
```

Comment: It worked. I was sure that I have done it already, but I must have made a mistake. Thank you! (and thanks for the RVM too)

Answer (score 0):

What Operating system are you running?
What are the JAVA OPTS environment variables set to?  JRuby consuming 7GB sounds unlikely under standard configuration - -J-Xmx is ususally set to something sane like 1024mb in the environments I've seen, and you have to explicitly override this to allocate more memory to the JVM.

try issuing the command:

```
jruby -J-Xmx1024m -S gem env
```

and post the content here.

Answer (score 0):

Running MacOS 10.8.5 and jruby 1.7.10 recently installed via brew,
I get:

```
jgem install mvp-0.0.8.gem --user-install
Error: Your application used more stack memory than the safety cap of 2048K.
Specify -J-Xss####k to increase it (#### = cap size in KB).
Specify -w for full StackOverflowError stack trace
```

Though many posts say the StackOverflowError is an rvm problem, the above doesn't seem to confirm this.

I can get around the problem when I run this:

```
jruby -J-Xmx1024m -S gem install mvp-0.0.8.gem  --user-install
Fetching: highline-1.6.21.gem (100%)
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/davei/.gem/jruby/1.9/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed highline-1.6.21
Fetching: mini_portile-0.5.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile-0.5.2
Fetching: nokogiri-1.6.1-java.gem (100%)
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.6.1-java
Fetching: builder-3.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.2
Successfully installed mvp-0.0.8
5 gems installed
```

So it looks to me like a problem with the jgem interface.
By the way, I tried many different settings of JRUBY_OPTS=-J-Xss####k with the jgem command and none (even up to 1GB) worked.  The error messages were the same except they reflected a new 'safety cap' size.